# Amazon AWS S3 how to track downloads from Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am looking for a way to track downloads of files that are stored in the amazon S3 service. I downloaded the API, and then I get pretty lost.  I just want to know what objects and methods I have to use from the API in order to get the information of the files stored there.  I want to track downloads including the addresses of those that make the requests.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: You talking about downloading from your logging bucket?

Comment: See the [AWS docs on Server Access Logging](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about downloading the files in a logging bucket, we use something like the following:

- connect to S3 (using the access/secret keys)
- open up the bucket entitled `"loggingBucket"`
- get each of the objects in that bucket
- read the file in and process it
- after we process each file, we remove it

Here's the sample code:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials =
    new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretAccessKey");
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

for (ObjectListing listing = client.listObjects("loggingBucket");;
        listing = client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing)) {
    // run through each listing to process it
    for (S3ObjectSummary summary : listing.getObjectSummaries()) {
        String bucketName = summary.getBucketName();
        String fileName = summary.getKey();
        S3Object object = client.getObject(bucketName, fileName);
        S3ObjectInputStream stream = object.getObjectContent();
        BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        ... process the file here writing it locally or something
        // delete the file afterwards
        client.deleteObject(bucketName, fileName);
    }
    // we may need to get more files
    if (!listing.isTruncated()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you want, please edit your post so we can help you better.

Comment: I guess this is not exaclty what i am looking for, what it really give an global idea of working with ASW. Thanks gray, your comment was the most constructive of all :)